# AngularJS app: how can I fetch date from the view and use it in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app in AngularJS 1.6, using the Giphy.com api.

The view displays, among others, an "import date". The parameter `import_datetime` comes from the API and is *item-specific*.

I have tempted to convert the date to a more user friendly format:

```
<p class="m-0 meta">{{giphy.import_datetime | date : "dd.MM.y" }}</p>
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

My controller has the flowing code:

```
app.controller("giphyCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "$timeout", function($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout) {
    var url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=PTZrBlrq8h2KUsRMeBuExZ5nHyn7dzS0&limit=240&rating=G";
    $scope.giphyList = [];
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.filterList = function() {
        var oldList = $scope.giphyList || [];
        $scope.giphyList = $filter('filter')($scope.giphys, $scope.search);
        if (oldList.length != 0) {
            $scope.pageNum = 1;
            $scope.startAt = 0;
        };
        $scope.itemsCount = $scope.giphyList.length;
        $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
    };

    $http.get(url)
        .then(function(data) {
            // giphy arary
            $scope.giphys = data.data.data;
            $scope.filterList();
            console.log($scope.giphys);

            // Paginate
            $scope.pageNum = 1;
            $scope.perPage = 24;
            $scope.startAt = 0;
            $scope.filterList();

            $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 500);
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
                    $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
                }, 0);
            };

            $scope.prevPage = function() {
                if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
                    $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
                    $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
                }
            };

            $scope.nextPage = function() {
                if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
                    $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
                    $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
                }
            };

            $scope.selectedIndex = null;
            $scope.selectedGiphy = null;

            $scope.fetchSinglegGiphy = function(giphy, index) {
                $scope.selectedIndex = index;
                $scope.selectedGiphy = giphy;
            }

        });

}]);
```

I should probably get fetch `import_datetime` from the view, convert it to a JavaScript Date object and the use it in he view.

**Questions:**

1. How can I do that?
2. Or what is a better alternative

Comment: Why do you want to pass on data from view to controller? Shouldn't it be vice-versa? You can implement you own filter reference - (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) and render the formatted data to view with function bound to your custom filter.

Comment: @SachinGadagi What I want is to display the date in a more friendly format. And only the date, not the hour. How would *you* do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter that will parse a date from giphy format to a JavaScript date object and pipe it to the AngularJS built-in `date` filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('dateParse', function() {
  return function(date) {
    return Date.parse(date);
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <p>{{'2019-07-10 14:12:59' | dateParse | date : "dd.MM.y"}}</p>
</div>
```